# How to export gpo rules on Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

I want to export the GPO rules of different sessions to reproduce them on another windows machine. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

For normal settings:

- Go to: `%systemroot%\system32\grouppolicy\`
- Copy 'machine' and 'user' folders to the`%systemroot%\system32\grouppolicy` of the target system.
- Refresh with `gpupdate /force` or reboot target system.

For security settings:

- Open MMC and add the snap-in “Security Templates”.
- Create your own template and save it as an “.inf” file.
- Copy the file to the target system and import it with command line tool “secedit”: `secedit /configure /db %temp%\temp.sdb /cfg securitysettings.inf`.